# What does question mark data in .data section mean in IDA?

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, ida

I use IDA to analyse an EXE and find something confusing. The `.data` section should contain **initialized data**, so every location should have something like this:

```
var_A db 0h
var_B dw 12h
```

But I get a lot of entries with question marks. e.g.

```
.data:00000001400F1680 qword_1400F1680 dq ?                    ; DATA XREF: sub_14004F8B0+8Er
.data:00000001400F1680                                         ; sub_1400539D0+12Aw ...
.data:00000001400F1688 qword_1400F1688 dq ?                    ; DATA XREF: sub_1400539D0+F5w
.data:00000001400F1688                                         ; sub_1400539D0+FCr
.data:00000001400F1690 qword_1400F1690 dq ?                    ; DATA XREF: sub_1400539D0+C0w
.data:00000001400F1690                                         ; sub_1400539D0+C7r
```

As far as I know, the `?` in x86 assembly means **uninitialized data**. But this is in the `.data` section! So are they really uninitialized, or the question mark in `db/dw/dd/dq` in IDA has a different meaning?

Comment: PE sections can be larger in memory than in the disk. See [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093168/ida-pro-disassembly-how-to-see-data-portion-in-plain-ascii/38094048](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093168/ida-pro-disassembly-how-to-see-data-portion-in-plain-ascii/38094048)

Comment: @MargaretBloom Right answer. thx.

Answer (score 0):

IDA Pro shows uninitialized value to '?'. 
The '?' marks appear .data section when the virtual size of the .data section is bigger than the raw size of the .data section. 
The addresses bigger than the virtual_address('.data')+raw_size('.data') show '?' marks.

db/dw/dd/dq has different meaning in IDA Pro. 
IDA Pro analyzes the assembly code and set type the location. 
db/dw/dd/dq means the instructions referencing the address uses 1/2/4/8 bytes respectively.